# Chart.js - Font only renders after you reload the canvas

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using Chart.js and I am trying to use a Google Font. The first time I load the page, the chart uses the default font but if I recreate the chart, then the correct font is loaded.

How do I get the font to load the first time the chart is loaded?

My HTML:

```
<div style="width: 100%;" id="StatsDiv">
    <div id="container" style="position: relative; height:300px; width:600px; background-color:#F9F9F9; padding-top:10px;">
        <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

The loading of the font:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap+Condensed:400,500,600" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The Javascript that does the work:

```
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Asap Condensed';

        var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: [FundsLabel,RequestedLabel],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "Cleared Balance: " + parseFloat(AVBalance).toFixed(2) + " AUD",
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(98,203,49,0.40)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(98,203,49,0.75)",
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(98,203,49,0.50)",
                        hoverBorderColor: "rgba(98,203,49,1.00)",
                        data: [AVBalance, GreenRequested],
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Pending Balance: " + parseFloat(PDBalance).toFixed(2) + " AUD",
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(231,76,60,0.40)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(231,76,60,0.75)",
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(231,76,60,0.50)",
                        hoverBorderColor: "rgba(231,76,60,1.00)",
                        data: [PDBalance, RedRequested],
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                        gridLines: {
                            display: true,
                            zeroLineColor: '#999999',
                            zeroLineWidth: '1',
                            // color: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
                            color: "rgba(239, 239, 239)",
                        },
                          ticks: {
                              //  min: 0, // it is for ignoring negative step.
                              beginAtZero: true,
                              fontSize: "12",

                                // if i use this it always set it '1', which look very awkward if it have high value  e.g. '100'.
                            }
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                        gridLines: {
                            display: false,

                        },

                        barThickness: 120,
                         scaleLabel: {
                             display: true,
                            //labelString: 'Banks'

                        }
                    }]
                },
                maintainAspectRatio: false,

            }
        });
```

Comment: are you loading the font before you create the chart?  If the font doesn't exist yet the chart won't use it.

Comment: I thought about that Andrew but how do we check if the font is loaded? (and yes the font loading happens before the font is created)

Comment: it seems to be working fine here https://jsfiddle.net/m21qx9kj/1/ are there any differences between that and your setup?

Answer (score 2):

wrapping the chart rendering code inside `document.fonts.ready.then` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The chart won't load your font on the first time because it couldn't find your font (yet). But it works the second time because your font is already cached by browser.

If you want to make sure the font is working, you can do preload the font by using a hidden DOM.

```css
.fontPreloader{
    font-family: 'Asap Condensed';
    position: fixed;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fontPreloader">-</div>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap+Condensed:400,500,600" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Nice find, thank you, I wonder if there's a way to do this without having to add content to the page re:"-" way off the the top left in the dom. Not that this is bad but just seems like there's got to be a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for the window to load before creating the chart worked for me:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // An example of creating a chart, replace with your code:
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var barchart = new Chart(ctx, config);  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    Chart.update();
}, 300);
```

wait time must be more than 100ms I think!